# Spring Integration Transformer's expression to set value to payload

Tags: java, spring-integration

I’m trying to use Spring integration transformer’s expression to set a value to payload.

My payload is an object with below variables

```
Private int id;
Private String name;

//getter
//setter
```

This is what my transformer looks like

```
<int:transformer input-channel="inChannel"
    output-channel="outChannel"
    expression="payload.name = ‘test’”/>
```

But I can’t get this to work. Am I making any mistake here?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases when you see SpEL expressions in Spring Integration channel adatapter, it is about "read-only" behavior. Just because the endpoint is two-way logic: receive a message from an input channel, perform an expression, build reply based on the expression evaluation result and produce it to the output channel.

The "set value" expression doesn't return anything, therefore this transformer won't know how to be next, even if we could support `write` for this kind of expression.

Luckily there is a component you are looking for.
It is a [Content Enricher](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DataEnricher.html) EI pattern implementation. In Spring Integration we call it `<payload-enricher>`. See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-transformation.html#payload-enricher. See also this sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/basic/enricher

Comment: thanks so much. I will try this and let you know. thanks again for taking time to answer.